# How to create Refresh Control at the bottom of UITableView Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3

How to create Refresh Control at the bottom of UITableView in Swift 3.0

Comment: you have to create this via programically  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
} in this method

Comment: no i will try but not done

Comment: what you try in your project upload snapcode that you use for create Uirefreshcontrol

Answer (score 13):

You can't add UIRefreshControl in tableview bottom but you can do it using UIActivityIndicatorView.It is not work like UIRefreshControl.You can not add target into it.you need to manage your self while load more data into tableview

```
 let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
 spinner.color = UIColor.darkGray
 spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
 tableView.tableFooterView = spinner
```

show spinner using

```
spinner.startAnimating()
```

hide it using

```
spinner.stopAnimating()
```